# Add conditional filter to ListView Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-filter, django-generic-views

I have list of events. Using ListView to render them.

**In models.py**

```
def event_date_time(self):
    event_date_time = datetime.combine(self.event_date, self.event_time)
    return event_date_time
```

In `ListView` i also have `now= datetime.utcnow()`

Need to add a filter to queryset.

```
if now > event_date_time:
     #don't render that event
else:
     #render
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a model function in Django filtering. You should use DateTimeField to store event_date and event_time in one attribute. Then, in your ListView, override the 'get_queryset' function like so:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Event.objects.filter(event_datetime__gte=datetime.now())
```